I got livewire/update 404 (Not Found) in JS console when wire:poll is triggered (and the render function is not called)
I got :
livewire.js?id=38dc8241:4284 POST http://localhost:8000/livewire/update 404 (Not Found) 

Everytime the wire:poll is triggered.
(and the render function is not called, except for the first time)
I use Laravel Framework 11.25.0 with Livewire v3.5.6
I remove almost all my code, but the errors is still there, even with this livewire view :
<div wire:poll>A</div>

With this livewire controller who basically do nothing ;
class TweetTable extends Component
{

    public function mount($campaign)
    {
        Log::info(__CLASS__ . ":" . __FUNCTION__ . " idCampaign = " . $campaign->id);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        Log::info(__CLASS__ . ":" . __FUNCTION__);

        return view('livewire.tweet-table');
    }
}

And I still have the error ...
When I do : php artisan route:list | grep update
I see :
 POST      livewire/update ..................................... livewire.update › Livewire\Mechanisms › HandleRequests@handleUpdate

Just before my </body> I have :
<script src="http://localhost:8000/vendor/livewire/livewire.js?id=38dc8241"   data-csrf="XlSYyXOXSjYqjzZ2YNN0Qs4vXTA8fkPkE68wQ7js" data-update-uri="/livewire/update" data-navigate-once="true"></script>

I can access to http://localhost:8000/livewire/update in my browser
(I got The GET method is not supported for route livewire/update. Supported methods: POST.   but this is normal)
Any ideas?
Thanks
